# Calculate submatrix with SAT in C++

Tags: c++

I have problem with summaring elements in my 2d submatrix.

My array after SAT:

```
-2 -4 -7 -6 
 1 -1 -3  1 
 2  3 -2  5 
 4  5  0  5
```

next, I have line with coordes of two vertexes (x1, y1, x2, y2) of submatrix and I try to calculate elements in that array.

I have code:

```
int result =
       tab[x2][y2] -
       tab[x1-1][y2] -
       tab[x2][y1-1] +
       tab[x1-1][y1-1];
```

The problem is when column or row is 0, then output is wrong because there is no elements (-1 index). Could you tell me how should I fix that for working?

Comment: Don't do the `-1` then? Its unclear what you're asking; you seem to be adding and subtracting corner elements from a submatrix but I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So should I add if (if, row or column = 0, then plus 0)?

Comment: I love acronyms, what is SAT?  The only one I know of is a college entrance examination.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table